# d3.js two graphs on same page is on top of each other

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have 2 graphs each in separate angular directive

```
<chart1 ng-model="data" style="display:block;" id="plot1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<svg width="960" height="500" style="right: 0px;">Some data</svg>
</chart1>
<chart2 ng-model="data" style="display:block;" id="plot1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<svg width="960" height="500" style="right: 0px;">Some data</svg>
</chart2>
```

chart1 generation of svg:

```
           var svg = d3.select("#plot1").append("svg")
               .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
               .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).style({'right': '0'});
```

chart 2 :

```
               var svg = d3.select("#plot2").append("svg")
               .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
               .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).style({'right': '0'});
```

for some reason those two graphs ends on top of each other, in html i can see that svg is stylled as position: absolute. if i remove this style everything works, but it i sstyle this way for a reason probably...

i come accross this guid: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/arranging-more-than-one-d3js-graph-on.html

but it didnt helped.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: If you need `position: absolute` then you need to set the positioning explicitly, e.g. `left: 0px` for the first graph and `right: 0px` for the second.

Comment: But really, unless *you* have a particular reason for using absolute positioning, it isn't necessary.  It doesn't change how the interior content of the graph is drawn.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that both of your chart tags are using the same id `id="plot1"`.

I'm not much of an expert on these things, but I'm fairly sure that id's should be unique.

From [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp):
"*The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).*"

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to use two different variables `var svg1` and `var svg2` in your scripts, because you know, the async functions will have trouble to find the correct svg element.

---

**Story:**

Google search took me here for having trouble to place two SVGs on a single DOM. Just check if this is your case.

The problem I faced:

- I had two chart elements on the same page; the ids, names were different.
- Both of them were at different portion of page, (generated using a template engine[GSP])
- Both the blocks had a similar script. The content was loaded from JSON API.
- *The chart contents were overlapped*

The actual problem:

- The variable names were messed up. Both the scripts used same variable `var svg=...` to refer to SVG element. The JSON response in async function from server was going to second SVG because its script reassigned `var svg=...`

The solution:

I used two different variables: `var svg1=...` and `var svg2=...`